# backbone all resource ready before render

Tags: backbone.js

when render a view in backbone you will need to have a couple of resource ready. it could be the list of country, city, and zipcode if you want to make dropdown list. I was wondering what is proper way so that every time render function is called all the resource is ready?

I am thinking using default render event I might go like this using Jquery defered?

```
render: function(){
    var listofajaxcall = setupResource(); //returns array of ajax call
    var self = this;
    $.when(listofajaxcall){
    }.done(){
       self.rendering();
    }
},
rendering: function(){
   //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's one way to do it, and is a common solution.

Returning a promise from the `setupResource` call will allow the view rendering to be deferred until the resource is ready.

One thing you might want to do in addition, is trigger an event from your `rendering` method to say when the view is done rendering:

```
render: function(){
    var listofajaxcall = setupResource(); //returns array of ajax call
    var self = this;
    $.when(listofajaxcall){
    }.done(){
       self.rendering();
    }
},
rendering: function(){
   //do something 

   // after it's done...
   this.trigger("rendered");
}
```

That way, you can listen to the rendered event and call additional code that needs to run after the view is rendered.

The other way that I prefer, is to have code outside of the view set things up, so that the view doesn't have to handle the async code.

```
var foo = {

  bar: function(){

    var listofajaxcall = setupResource();

    var self = this;
    $.when(listofajaxcall).then(someResource){

       var view = new MyView({
         someResource: someResource
       });
       view.render();
       $("#whatever").html(view.el);

    }
  }

}

foo.bar();
```

In this version of the code, the view doesn't know anything about being asynchronous. It's the code that controls the flow of logic in the app that knows about it. The downside to this is that you if you want to put a "loading..." message on the screen, you have to render another view first. This is worth it IMO, because it makes the flow of work being done more explicit.

Comment: Another option is for the view to be smart enough to render incomplete data, if something isn't loaded then listen for an event and re-render all or part of the view when it is ready; this way the view handle its own loader. This gets ugly when you're waiting for more than a couple chunks of AJAX data though.